# Spherical harmonics for dummies

Tags: spherical-harmonics

Adding to the [for dummies](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22for+dummies%22).

[The real spherical harmonics are orthonormal basis functions on the surface of a sphere.](http://www.paulsprojects.net/opengl/sh/technical.html)

I'd like to fully understand that sentence and what it means.

Still grappling with

- Orthonormal basis functions (I believe this is like Fourier Transform's basis functions are sines and cosines, and sin is orthogonal to cos, and so the components can have a zero inner product..)
- ".. are orthonormal basis functions ..**on the surface of a sphere**".

  - **What sphere**?  Where does the sphere come from?  Do you mean for each position on the sphere, we have a value?  Is the periodicity in space on the sphere exploited?  Is that how we get the higher order terms?

Comment: Did you read the wikipedia page? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics

Comment: Yes.  That wiki page is pretty opaque to me at the moment.

Comment: A "function on X" is generally a function from X to R. So a function on the surface of a sphere is a function from, say, {(x, y, z) : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1} to R. (I'm not sure what "what sphere" means.)

Comment: @bobobobo, you may be interested in the recent book: http://www.amazon.com/Applications-Fractional-Calculus-Physics-Hilfer/dp/9810234570

Answer (score 19):

I think the point that was confusing me/missing link was that spherical harmonics functions **are the solution of** the Laplace's differential equation:

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial z^2}=0$$

Orthogonal means the functions "pull in different directions".  Like in linear algebra, orthogonal vectors "pull" in completely "distinct" directions in n-space, it turns out that orthogonal functions "help you reach completely distinct values", where the resultant value (sum of functions) is again a function.

SH are **based** on the [associated Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomial), (which are a tad more funky than [Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials), namely each band has more distinct functions defined for it for the associated ones.)

The Legendre polynomials themselves, like SH, are orthogonal functions.  So if you take any 2 functions from the Legendre polynomial set, they're going to be orthogonal to each other (integral on $[-1,1]$ is $0$), and if you add scaled copies of one to the other, you're going to be able to reach *an entirely distinct set of functions/values* than you could with just one of those basis functions alone.

Now the **sphere** comes from the idea that, SH functions, **use** the Legendre polynomials (but Legendre polynomials are 1D functions), and the **specification** of spherical harmonics is **a function value for every $\phi \theta$**.  There is no "sphere" per se.. it's like if you say "there is a value for every point on the unit circle", it means you trace a circle around the origin and give each point a value.

What is meant is **every point on a unit sphere has a numeric value**.  If we associate a **color** to every point on the sphere, you get a visualization like this:

[image: viz sh colors]

[This page](http://people.csail.mit.edu/sparis/sh/index.php?img=64) shows a visualization where the values of the SH function are used to MORPH THE SPHERE (which is part of what was confusing me earlier).  But just because a function has values **for every point on the sphere** doesn't mean *there is a sphere*.

Comment: [This paper by Volker Schönefeld](http://limbicsoft.com/volker/prosem_paper.pdf) shows a good introduction to SH with excellent visualizations

Comment: That paper.  Changed my life with spherical harmonics.  Thank you for bringing this up.  IMO this paper should be the top answer!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the "morph the sphere" bit?

Comment: Can somebody link this paper or give a proper reference as the original link is broken.

Answer (score 16):

$\theta$ and $\phi$ the coordinates of a spherical surface.  They are similar to latitude ($\theta$) and longitude ($\phi$) except that $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$ and $\phi$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$.  Each harmonic has a value at every point, for example $Y_1^{-1}(\theta,\phi)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2\pi}}\sin(\theta)e^{-i\phi}$.  Given the coordinates you can calculate the value.  The orthogonality is because if you integrate the product of any two different harmonics over the surface of the sphere, you get $0$.

Comment: To add for @bobobobo: "The orthogonality is because if you integrate the product of any two different harmonics over the surface of the sphere, you get 0." - that takes care of the "ortho-" part of "orthonormal"; the "-normal" portion is because the factors in front of the defining expression for spherical harmonics were set so that the integral of the square of a spherical harmonic over the sphere's surface is 1.