# Spherical harmonics as orthonormal basis in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spherical-harmonics

In this article https://mrtrix.readthedocs.io/en/dev/concepts/spherical_harmonics.html the following statement is given:

> Spherical harmonics are special functions defined on the surface of a sphere. They form a complete orthonormal set and can therefore be used to represent any well-behaved spherical function.

I have two questions:

**1. What does it means "functions defined on the surface of a sphere"? Functions whose domain is given by $(\theta,\phi)$ with $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ and $\phi \in [0,2\pi]$?**

**2. Why spherical harmonics form an orthonormal basis for the space of functions defined on the sphere? Since spherical harmonics are also simultaneous eigenfunctions of operators $L^2$ and $L_z$, don't they form a basis for any function?**

Comment: "Since spherical harmonics are also simultaneous eigenfunctions of operators $L^2$ and $L_z$, don't they form a basis for any function?" - Why do you think so?

Comment: @Filippo If 2 operators commute, they have a set of simultaneous eigenfunctions which is also a basis.

Comment: Yes, but why do you believe that the spherical harmonics are not only simultanous eigenfunctions, but even a basis for the functions on $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Since spherical harmonics aren't functions defined on $\mathbb R^3$, this doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @Filippo Ok so this is the point, spherical harmonics are a basis only for functions defined on the sphere?

Comment: Yes. But the spherical harmonics are also useful to construct a basis for the functions on $\mathbb R^3$. If $Y=Y(\theta,\phi)$ is a function on the sphere and $R=R(r)$ is defined on the positive real numbers, then $f(r,\theta,\phi):=R(r)Y(\theta,\phi)$ is a function on $\mathbb R^3$ (via spherical coordinates).

Comment: @Filippo Ok thank you. Can you help with my first question? What do we mean by functions defined on the sphere?

Comment: I will add an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate in the Related sidebar: [Spherical harmonics for dummies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24671/spherical-harmonics-for-dummies?rq=1).

Comment: I need to know how much you already know. You know about spherical coordinates, don't you?

Comment: @Filippo yes of course. I know about Laplacian in spherical coordinates, I know how to obtain spherical harmonics from laplace equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does "functions defined on the surface of a sphere" mean?

You can literally define the spherical harmonics on a sphere:

In your article, the following formula is given:
$$Y_l^m(\theta,\phi) = \sqrt{\frac{(2l+1)}{4\pi}\frac{(l-m)!}{(l+m)!}} P_l^m(\cos \theta) e^{im\phi}$$
Clearly, $Y(\theta,\phi)$ is well defined for all $(\theta,\phi)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$. On the other hand\begin{align}F\colon[0,\pi]\times\mathbb R&\to S\\(\theta,\phi)&\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}\sin\theta\cos\phi\\\sin\theta\sin\phi\\\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\end{align} is a surjective function to the sphere. Thus, if a spherical harmonic $Y$ is constant on the level sets of $F$, we can define $Y$ on the sphere by requiring that $$(Y\circ F)(\theta,\phi)=Y(\theta,\phi)$$for all $(\theta,\phi)\in[0,\pi]\times\mathbb R$ (note the slight abuse of notation).

Well, it turns out that spherical harmonics are indeed constant on level sets of $F$: For the north pole and the south pole, you can find the explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4384892/572841) and for the other points on the sphere - i.e. the points with $0<\theta<\pi$ - this is easy to prove.

Comment: I didn't understand anything. What is S? What is F? Why spherical harmonics are defined on $R\times R$ and not on $[0,π]\times[0,2π]$? And I still can't get the definition of functions defined on a sphere. as far as I've understood, a functions is defined over a sphere if it is a functions of type: $f(\theta,\phi):[0,π]\times[0,2π] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, but I can't understand what your answer is about.

Comment: @Salmone $S$ is the sphere with radius $1$:$$S:=\{x\in\mathbb R^3:\|x\|=1\}$$

Comment: @Salmone Of course, we can consider spheres centered in different points and with different radii. But given some sphere, it makes sense to choose its center as the origin of our coordinate system and its radius as our unit of length, so that we always end up working with $S$.

Comment: @Salmone "And I still can't get the definition of functions defined on a sphere" - When I say that a function $f$ is defined on the sphere, I mean it, i.e. the sphere $S$ is the domain of $f$. The set $[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi]$ is a rectangle, not a sphere.

Comment: @Salmone Is everything clear up to this point?

Comment: Yep, thank you.

Comment: @Salmone I'm glad to hear that. To put it into a nutshell: If $$F\colon [0,\pi]\times\mathbb R\to S$$ was bijective, then given a spherical harmonic $Y\colon [0,\pi]\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ we could simply take the composition $Y\circ F^{-1}\colon S\to\mathbb C$ to obtain a function defined on $S$. However, $F$ is not injective, this is why we need to verify that $Y$ is constant on the level sets of $F$: Since $F$ is surjective, it induces a bijective function $\tilde{F}$ on the set of all level sets, and since $Y$ is constant on the level sets,

Comment: it induces a function $\tilde{Y}$ on the set of all level sets. Thus, we can consider the composition $\tilde{Y}\circ\tilde{F}^{-1}\colon S\to\mathbb C$.

Comment: No, I can't understand anything of this. Why do I need to know all of these things? I just wanted to know the definition of functions defined on a sphere.

Comment: @Salmone As you pointed out, the article says that spherical harmonics are defined on the sphere, but the formula that is given in that article does not define the spherical harmonics on the sphere, but on $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$. I explained how you can use that formula do define the spherical harmonics on the sphere. Unfortunately, this involves a lot of technicalities. Anyways, the conclusion is that you can indeed think of the spherical harmonics as being defined on the sphere.

Comment: I think I'll go with that because the rest is too hard for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Salmone Thank you for the discussion - when I had my QM lecture, I had similar issues and it was nice to revisit that stuff. I guess this was too much at once, but if you have any questions later on, don't hesitate to ask :) One more comment (I hope that you'll find it intriguing and understand it properly later on): The reason for all this complications is essentially that the sphere is nontrivial manifold - we can not cover it by a single chart. But it is "nearly" a trivial manifold: If we restrict $F$ to the open rectangle $]0,\pi[\times]0,2\pi[$, then $F$ is injective and

Comment: "nearly" surjective, in the sense that the image contains all points of the sphere apart from the line connecting the north pole and the south pole with $\phi=2\pi$. But if integrate over the sphere, this doesn't really matter (since the area of a line is zero), that's why this is swept under the rug.

Comment: Thank for your time and kindness. Maybe in ten years I'll try to understand "trivial manifold".